# Soundspectrum As3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I'm currently working on a soundgame in actionscript. I can get all sorts of variables through different methods in actionscript.. but my question is;

How can I track low-frequency tones and high-frequency tones through Soundspectrum (and thus the bytes you get returned in a ByteArray).

If I know where the tones are located, I can pull out those data from the Array .. or doesn't it work that way?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SoundMixer.computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29) with FFTMode enabled it will generate a ByteArray in frequency order.  You can then trim this to match you desired range.

Answer (score 0):

this simple code snipet demonstrate that you can grab bytes values:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(bytes, false, 0);
trace(bytes.readFloat());
```